# Shortcode is not working in my post list page

Tags: wordpress

Please check the URL: https://channelc.net/newsite/podcasts/

The shortcode is not working. The shortcode is displaying as the code itself on the frontend. Can anybody please help me that how can I make the shortcode work in the frontend? Is there somehow the conversion from shortcode to the desired element is being prevented by the code I am using?

The code I am using is:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_demo_load_my_posts', 'demo_load_my_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_demo_load_my_posts', 'demo_load_my_posts' );
function demo_load_my_posts() {
       
    global $wpdb;
   
    $msg = '';
   
    if( isset( $_POST['data']['page'] ) ){
        // Always sanitize the posted fields to avoid SQL injections
        $page = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']['page']); // The page we are currently at
        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']['th_name']); // The name of the column name we want to sort
        $sort = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']['th_sort']); // The order of our sort (DESC or ASC)
        $cur_page = $page;
        $page -= 1;
        $per_page = 10; // Number of items to display per page
        $previous_btn = true;
        $next_btn = true;
        $first_btn = true;
        $last_btn = true;
        $start = $page * $per_page;
       
        // The table we are querying from  
        $posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
       
        $where_search = '';
       
        // Check if there is a string inputted on the search box
        if( ! empty( $_POST['data']['search']) ){
            // If a string is inputted, include an additional query logic to our main query to filter the results
            $where_search = ' AND (post_title LIKE "%%' . $_POST['data']['search'] . '%%" OR post_content LIKE "%%' . $_POST['data']['search'] . '%%") ';
        }
       
        // Retrieve all the posts
        $all_posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM $posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' $where_search
            ORDER BY $name $sort LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ) );
       
        $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM " . $posts . " WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' $where_search", array() ) );
       
        // Check if our query returns anything.
        if( $all_posts ):
            $msg .= '<table class = "table table-striped table-hover table-file-list">';
           
            // Iterate thru each item
            foreach( $all_posts as $key => $post ):
                $msg .= '
                <tr>
                    <td width = "60%">' . $post->post_content . '</td>
                </tr>';        
            endforeach;
           
            $msg .= '</table>';
       
        // If the query returns nothing, we throw an error message
        else:
            $msg .= '<p class = "bg-danger">No posts matching your search criteria were found.</p>';
           
        endif;

        $msg = "<div class='cvf-universal-content'>" . $msg . "</div><br class = 'clear' />";
       
        $no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

        if ($cur_page >= 7) {
            $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
            if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
                $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
            else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
                $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            } else {
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            }
        } else {
            $start_loop = 1;
            if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
                $end_loop = 7;
            else
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
        }
         
        $pag_container .= "
        <div class='cvf-universal-pagination'>
            <ul>";

        if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
        } else if ($first_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
        }

        if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
            $pre = $cur_page - 1;
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
        } else if ($previous_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
        }
        for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

            if ($cur_page == $i)
                $pag_container .= "<li p='$i' class = 'selected' >{$i}</li>";
            else
                $pag_container .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
        }
       
        if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            $nex = $cur_page + 1;
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
        } else if ($next_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
        }

        if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
        } else if ($last_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
        }

        $pag_container = $pag_container . "
            </ul>
        </div>";
       
        echo
        '<div class = "cvf-pagination-content">' . $msg . '</div>' .
        '<div class = "cvf-pagination-nav">' . $pag_container . '</div>';
       
    }
   
    exit();
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_demo_load_my_posts', 'demo_load_my_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_demo_load_my_posts', 'demo_load_my_posts' );
function demo_load_my_posts() {
    
    global $wpdb;
    $msg = '';
   
    if( isset( $_POST['data']['page'] ) ){
        // Always sanitize the posted fields to avoid SQL injections
        $page = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']['page']); // The page we are currently at
        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']['th_name']); // The name of the column name we want to sort
        $sort = sanitize_text_field($_POST['data']['th_sort']); // The order of our sort (DESC or ASC)
        $cur_page = $page;
        $page -= 1;
        $per_page = 10; // Number of items to display per page
        $previous_btn = true;
        $next_btn = true;
        $first_btn = true;
        $last_btn = true;
        $start = $page * $per_page;
        $author = the_author_meta("ID");
       
        // The table we are querying from  
        $posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
       
        $where_search = '';
       
        // Check if there is a string inputted on the search box
        if( ! empty( $_POST['data']['search']) ){
            // If a string is inputted, include an additional query logic to our main query to filter the results
            $where_search = ' AND (post_title LIKE "%%' . $_POST['data']['search'] . '%%" OR post_content LIKE "%%' . $_POST['data']['search'] . '%%") ';
        }
       
        // Retrieve all the posts
        $all_posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM $posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_author = $author $where_search ORDER BY $name $sort LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ) );
       echo $post->post_author;
        $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM " . $posts . " WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' $where_search", array() ) );
       
        // Check if our query returns anything.
        if( $all_posts ):
            $msg .= '<table width = "100%">';
           
            // Iterate thru each item
            foreach( $all_posts as $key => $post ):
                $msg .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>' . do_shortcode($post->post_content) . '</td>
                    <td>' . $post->post_author . '</td>
                </tr>';        
            endforeach;
           
            $msg .= '</table>';
       
        // If the query returns nothing, we throw an error message
        else:
            $msg .= '<p class = "bg-danger">No posts matching your search criteria were found. </p>';
        
        endif;

        $msg = "<div class='cvf-universal-content'>" . $msg . "</div><br class = 'clear' />";
       
        $no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

        if ($cur_page >= 7) {
            $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
            if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
                $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
            else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
                $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            } else {
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            }
        } else {
            $start_loop = 1;
            if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
                $end_loop = 7;
            else
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
        }
         
        $pag_container .= "
        <div class='cvf-universal-pagination'>
            <ul>";

        if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
        } else if ($first_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
        }

        if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
            $pre = $cur_page - 1;
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
        } else if ($previous_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
        }
        for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

            if ($cur_page == $i)
                $pag_container .= "<li p='$i' class = 'selected' >{$i}</li>";
            else
                $pag_container .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
        }
       
        if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            $nex = $cur_page + 1;
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
        } else if ($next_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
        }

        if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
        } else if ($last_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
        }

        $pag_container = $pag_container . "
            </ul>
        </div>";
       
        echo
        '<div class = "cvf-pagination-content">' . $msg . '</div>' .
        '<div class = "cvf-pagination-nav">' . $pag_container . '</div>';
       
    }
   
    exit();
   
}
```